# Inline if shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

Is it possible to execute shell script in command line like this :

```
counter=`ps -ef | grep -c "myApplication"`; if [ $counter -eq 1 ] then; echo "true";
>
```

Above example is not working I get only `>` character not the result I'm trying to get, that is "true"

When I execute `ps -ef | grep -c "myApplication` I get 1 output. Is it possible to create result from single line in a script ? thank you

Comment: you need `; then` instead of `then;`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It doesn't work because you missed out `fi` to end your `if` statement.

```
counter=`ps -ef | grep -c "myApplication"`; if [ $counter -eq 1 ]; then echo "true"; fi
```

You can shorten it further using:

```
if [ $(ps -ef | grep -c "myApplication") -eq 1 ]; then echo "true"; fi
```

Also, do take note the issue of `ps -ef | grep ...` matching itself as mentioned in [@DigitalRoss' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986109/inline-if-shell-script/4986139#4986139).

#### update

In fact, you can do one better by using `pgrep`:

```
if [ $(pgrep -c "myApplication") -eq 1 ]; then echo "true"; fi
```

Comment: `if pgrep myApplication 2>/dev/null; then ...` No need for brackets or command substitution. The bracket around the "m" isn't needed either since pgrep doesn't match itself unless you tell it to.

Comment: That won't be accurate if he wants to match exactly one instance. Good point about pgrep not matching self. Updated example. Thanks.

Comment: In the first code example, is the semi-color after `then` in the wrong place?

Comment: `-c` for pgrep is not a valid switch at least for version 3.2.8 of procps. It's not working in my case...

Answer (score 10):

Other responses have addressed your syntax error, but I would strongly suggest you change the line to:

```bash
test $(ps -ef | grep -c myApplication) -eq 1 && echo true
```

If you are not trying to limit the number of occurrences to exactly 1 (eg, if you are merely trying to check for the output line myApplication and you expect it never to appear more than once) then just do:

```
ps -ef | grep myApplication > /dev/null && echo true
```

(If you need the variable counter set for later processing, neither of these solutions will be appropriate.)

Using short circuited && and || operators is often much clearer than embedding if/then constructs, especially in one-liners.

Answer (score 8):

#### Yes, with syntax issues fixed

That *almost* worked. The correct syntax is:

```
counter=`ps -ef | grep -c "myApplication"`; if [ $counter -eq 1 ]; then echo "true"; fi
```

But note that in an expression of this sort involving `ps` and `grep`, the `grep` will usually match itself because the characters "grep -c Myapplication" show up in the ps listing. There are several ways around that, one of them is to grep for something like `[M]yapplication`.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Mac OS and following worked very well

```
$ counter=`ps -ef | grep -c "myApplication"`; if [ $counter -eq 1 ]; then echo "true";fi;
```

true

Space is needed after [ and before ]

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to combine both multiple lines feed into command and getting its results into a variable (not a file) and come up with this solution:

```
    FRA_PARAM="'db_recovery_file_dest'"
    FRA=$(
    sqlplus -S "/as sysdba" <<EOF
set echo off head off feed off newpage none pages 1000 lines 1000
select value from v\$parameter where name=$FRA_PARAM;
exit;
EOF
        )
```

Please note that single-quotes word was substituted, because otherwise I was receiving its autosubstitution to double quotes... ksh, HP-UX.

Hopefully this will be helpful for somebody else too.