# Angular page reload issue due to browser cache

Tags: html, angular, caching, browser, reload

A Page on my website loads perfectly for very first time but if i reload it, it gets struck untill we clear browser cache.

Why is this happenng?
How can we resolve it?

Below is the code

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="ENoESU-ILobE1sHAs8D6mm3S3CohuUHq9ivlMeT2szI" />

    <title>My Activity Sheet</title>

    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href="<%url('favicon.ico')%>" />
    <!-- Core Css -->
    <link href="<% asset('static/vendors/angular-select/ui-select.css') %>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<% asset('css/mas.css') %>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<% asset('css/responsive.css') %>" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="<% asset('static/vendors/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css') %>" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="<% asset('static/vendors/dateipcker-angular/angular-datepicker.min.css') %>" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.gantt/latest/angular-gantt.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.gantt/latest/angular-gantt-plugins.min.css"/>
    @yield('pageLevelCSS')
    <style>
        .selectize-control > .selectize-dropdown {
            top: 36px;
        }
    </style>

    @yield('pageLevelHeadJs')
    <script>
```

Comment: Can you share the link to test?

Comment: `ng build --aot --output-hashing=all` if you have caching problem with each build file

Comment: @JoelJoseph Please explain

Comment: @RobeySingh if you have the cache issue check this article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/55403095#55403095

Comment: @RobeySingh but most probably its some logical problem in your app , did you check your browser console to see if there are any errors ? may be you lost some route param to the page or some parameter that is passed to the component, which must have lost on page reload

Comment: @JoelJoseph console errors are as follows :

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at /static/vendors/angular-select/select.min.js:7
    at /static/vendors/angular-select/select.min.js:7
angular.js:3650 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module userApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.select due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.select' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @RobeySingh make sure you are loading dependencies in correct order, first will be Angular, rest all dependencies in sequence