# Angular - Prod Build not generating unique hashes

Tags: angular, firebase, caching, hash

Angular production build is not generating unique hashes in my project.

**Below are the build logs screenshot**

[image]

Not able to reproduce this issue in new angular cli project, seems there is some issue in my project.

I am using angular - 6.0.3

Below is the angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "exampleProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/exampleProject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "sitemap.xml",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "googled41787c6aae2151b.html",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "CNAME",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/assets/css/reset.css",
              "src/assets/css/loading.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
             "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/modernizr.js",
              "src/assets/js/gtm.js"
              
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "baseHref": "/",
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "exampleProject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "exampleProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "exampleProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "exampleProject-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "exampleProject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "exampleProject:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "exampleProject"
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, Or provide any work around.

**EDIT:**

I have tried

```
ng build --aot --output-hashing=all
ng build --output-hashing=all
```

Still this produce same hashing for script.js, even after changing content in typescript or html.

### Read this before reading the answers

I had an issue in firebase not angular, I misunderstood that compiled code will be bundled as `scripts.js` but no, the bundled code is in `main.js`.

### My real issue was

I had a firebase cache rule and even after disabling it, it was still loading from the cache for users who previously visited my application, So I deleted and created a new firebase project which solved my issue.

Comment: the question is already answered  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/55403095

Comment: @JoelJoseph That doesn't seems to work, also question updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty of other people that face the same issue with you. [Check Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10641).

I don't think you'll find a solution to your problem if there isn't one on the official angular cli github, but based on the replies, can you please try updating your congifuration with the following and let me know if it works?

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
```

## Edit: Expected files to change

Your actual code is only in main.js (which I can see gets a new hash). The rest of the files will seldom change. Check what the files mean [here](https://itnext.io/how-to-optimize-angular-applications-99bfab0f0b7c)

> main.js contains all our code including components (ts, html and css
>   codes), pipes, directives, services and all other imported modules
>   (including third party).
>
> scripts.js contains the scripts we declare in the scripts section of
>   angular.json file

```
"scripts": [
   "myScript.js",
]
```

Comment: My current **angular.json** file includes the code you provided, I have already added full code of my angular.json in the question. Still Hashes are identical

Comment: You ARE changing the content right? If the code remains the same, then no new hashes are generated (by design).

Comment: Ya! I am aware of **"hashes are changed per bundled content, not per build"**, I changed lot of code/content still same output/hashes

Comment: Then I'd just go with updating my cli, as this looks like a recurring problem in some versions.

Comment: By the way, in your example images, there are new hashes generated for the main and polyfill. You haven't missed that, right? Only main js makes sense to change, as well as the lazy loaded modules.

Comment: What about **script.js**

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, So this seems to be another cache issue not related to angular build hashing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202641/discussion-between-sameer-khan-and-athanasios-kataras).

Comment: It's terrible they can even reopen the issue. No one knows how to fix this and it's been an issue for so long. Why even lazy load modules if it causes this many problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this issue in my project(Angular cli 14.2.10, I have upgraded from 13v) and I have realized one important thing: If I change `app.component.html|ts` or other components related to this component and after building my project, The name of hashed files are differently from previous hashed files. But If I change other components and then build my project, The hash value of Generated files are the same with previous hash value. So for this case the solution is doing some unnecessary change in `app.component`.

Comment: yes, after making changes in the app.component, a new hash is generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 7+ then you can use the command given below

```
ng build --configuration production --output-hashing all
```

Make sure you have the configuration set in your angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue i observed is hash only changes when we make any code changes in application. but for styles and polyfills the tag is same.

| Initial Chunk Files | Names | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main-es5.4daebf996f3ead829477.js | main | 759.75 kB |
| main-es2015.4daebf996f3ead829477.js | main | 682.24 kB |
| styles.427122a7a8ba74646062.css | styles | 477.01 kB |
| polyfills-es5.d7b40cf62085282501b1.js | polyfills-es5 | 131.97 kB |
| polyfills-es2015.2823b1a5ccf71efe2bde.js | polyfills | 36.11 kB |
| runtime-es2015.a4dadbc03350107420a4.js | runtime | 1.45 kB |
| runtime-es5.a4dadbc03350107420a4.js | runtime | 1.45 kB |

Build at: 2022-06-06T09:50:45.524Z - Hash: 5658eef36186f2e20989 - Time: 150810ms

| Initial Chunk Files | Names | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main-es5.d9483ea4d4880b3e0771.js | main | 759.67 kB |
| main-es2015.d9483ea4d4880b3e0771.js | main | 682.15 kB |
| styles.427122a7a8ba74646062.css | styles | 477.01 kB |
| polyfills-es5.d7b40cf62085282501b1.js | polyfills-es5 | 131.97 kB |
| polyfills-es2015.2823b1a5ccf71efe2bde.js | polyfills | 36.11 kB |
| runtime-es2015.a4dadbc03350107420a4.js | runtime | 1.45 kB |
| runtime-es5.a4dadbc03350107420a4.js | runtime | 1.45 kB |

Build at: 2022-06-06T09:54:59.714Z - Hash: 2431d248bc6f790fcb91 - Time: 145432ms