# Ionic 5 - cache problem when deploying new version

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I use Ionic 5 webapp, and when I deploy a new version of my application, the user receive a notification to download the new version. After the downloading, the application doesn't work anymore, but if the user  remove the cache of his phone, the application works again. This is very annoying, Is any one have the same problem and solved it?

Comment: are you saving anything in localstorage?

Comment: The assetGroups in my ngsw-config.json
`"assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.png",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/svg/**",
          "/*.(eot|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)" ]
      }
    }
  ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular app has to clear cache after new deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment)

Comment: @JoelJoseph it doesn't work yet. I already add no-cache in the meta of my index.html but I still have the same problem

Comment: I find my problem, I cached every thing in my dataGroups section. Thank's guys for your help