# How can I force update an Angular+Ionic PWA if a previous deployment did not include SWUpdate?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

We have deployed a version of our PWA with clients and made shortcuts on the home screen with a version that did not have the SWUpdate mechanism which refreshes and updates the app.

Is there any way to get those versions to trigger a refresh of the entire app?  The versions that do not have SWUpdate mechanism built in?

Comment: please check this , may help you : https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#updating-your-application-in-the-browser

Comment: also this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/55403095#55403095

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems cache busting is a common issue which seems to have solutions for Ionic.  Really appreciate it.