# What is the use of ng build -prod --output-hashing none?

Tags: angular

What is the use of this command?

```
ng build -prod --output-hashing none
```

> --output-hashing none you can avoid these hash names.

What is the exact use --output-hashing? Is this properties use in future or I stick to one command

```
ng build -prod
```

Comment: When you build an Angular application Angular, by defect create files like, e.g. `main-es2015.9373ed4f39039fa4b866.js`, `polyfills-es5.1fd9b76218eca8053895.js` ... If you don't want Angular add this "hash", use -output-hassing=none, so your files becomes like `main-es2015.js`, `polyfills-es5.js` ... (you can also change the angular.json to indicate you don't want the "hash" changing the build-->configuration-->outputHashing and use 'none'

Comment: you can refer here for answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/55403095#55403095

Answer (score 1):

The command can be used to build a project of type "application" or "library". ... A "production" configuration is created by default when you use the CLI to create the project, and you can use that configuration by specifying the --configuration where -- is just a notation for flaging