# What is the use of --output-hashing=all in angular build?

Tags: angular

When we create build for production then we use a command as -

```
ng build --aot --output-hashing=all --prod --base-href "/xyz/" --deploy-url "/xyz/"
```

What is use of `--output-hashing=all`?

Comment: In  the Angular documentation https://angular.io/cli/build you can see what each option is doing.

Comment: the explanation to your question can be obtained in another question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/55403095#55403095

Answer (score 24):

From [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build):

> Define the output filename cache-busting hashing mode.

So, if your parameter is `all`, your generated files would look like:

```
main.62beb1fb93041eb44194.js
```

Comment: Right, they are generated as such, but even after clearing browser cache it's still trying to find the js files without the #'s in their name. So "chunk load failed" is appearing in browser console and pages are not accessible.

Comment: that is because your browser caches the "index.html"... You should set according HTTP cache control headers to tell the browser to never cache the index.html