# Angular cache clear after add new changes to production mode

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 9.0.3 after add new change I'm upload it to Cpanel compile using this command
`ng build --prod --aot --outputHashing=all --extractCss=true` but after upload it if I go to website enter  URL its load old site after reload page it apply the new change how can remove that cache after upload new file to cpanel

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 9, You need to add `--output-hashing=all` instead of `--outputHashing=all` when you take production build.

Ref: [Angular app has to clear cache after new deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/55403095)