# Angular - Changes are not shown in production until customer refresh the page or cleaning cache

Tags: angular, deployment, build, settings

Every time Im deploying the angular app for production Im concern if customer will see new features added since some customers have reported that they are not seeing changes made until they refresh the page or when cleaning cache.

What would be the best option in order to solve this? (Angular 8+)

This is the command that Im using to deploy the app:
ng build --base-href=./ --sourceMap=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pls try `ng build --prod --aot --base-href=./ --outputHashing=all`

for more pls refer [Angular app has to clear cache after new deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment)