Hard Reload (Ctrl Shift R) Code Behind in Angular
Wanted to implement Same behaviour ( Ctrl + Shift + R) Using Angular code.
I am using Window.location.reload() and it's not working in chrome and edge.
I don't want user to press Ctrl + Shift + R every-time, i implement touble login link, when user click on that, i want Ctrl + Shift + R to be execute.
Please help
Regards

what is the reason, you want to achieve this, let me guess, is it because you need to ctrl+ shift + r to get the new deployed changes? if yes check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280027/angular-changes-are-not-shown-in-production-until-customer-refresh-the-page-or

yes, i have applied many changes to do this but it's not woking thrrough code , when i click on CTRL+shit+  r it get started woking but after few hour again same issue and i have to manualy do ctrl+shift+r ... even i have added code to load fresh copy of index.html eveytime when. user login or refresh

we already implemented above link in the code
