# I have to clear cache in browser after deploy an angular app to see changes

Tags: angular, caching

I have a strange problem with angular 13 app.After i deploy a new version i have to clear cache in browser otherwise it functional as before.I know its very strange.Is there i way to disable cache for one component in Angular?

Comment: You can find the answer to your problem in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403095/8135441

Answer (score 1):

you have to add "outputHashing": "all", in build -> configuration -> production in angular.json.

Comment: It was the outputHashing on all and it did despite

Comment: share angular.json and command that you use to build.