# How to update our website to latest version using JavaScript ? Basically Hard Reload or Clear cache and reload

Tags: javascript, angular, auto-update, clear-cache

I have deployed the latest version of my website, but until I do Clear cache and reload, My website is not updating automatically. How can I do this in the code using JavaScript? Thanks in advance.

I have tried using

1. `window.location.reload()`
2. `location.reload()`
3. 

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But nothing were working as expected.

Comment: Is it a PWA? In that case all your files are cached by the serviceWorker. You need to increment the `"version"` in `ngsw-config.json`, and call [`SwUpdate`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L87) from code. Obviously you'll still need a hard reload to get this new version, but then you should be fine

Comment: Have you tried using the --output-hashing=all flag when building ? More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/55403095#55403095)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Angular application, I had the same issue.

My solution was to clear the cache memory and also update the HTML page content.

> Here is an example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
            const content = await 
            window.fetch(location.host).then(response =>{ 
            htmlContent = response.text();
            location.reload(true)})
}, 1000)
```

I hope this help